# Assign same value to different ndarray indices - Python

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment

The question may not be clear, so I you explain with the code:

```
@staticmethod
def generate_data_uncertainty_heat_map(data_property, data_uncertainty, file_path):
    plt.figure()
    uncertainty = numpy.zeros((data_property.rows, data_property.cols, 4), 'uint8')
    uncertainty[..., 0] = uncertainty[..., 1] = uncertainty[..., 2] = numpy.uint8(data_property * 255)
    uncertainty[..., 3] = numpy.uint8(data_uncertainty)
    fig = plt.imshow(uncertainty, extent=[0, data_property.cols, data_property.rows, 0])
    plt.colorbar(fig)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

What this does is take two (n,n) ndarrays to form an RGBA image with **matploblib**.
To do such thing, I use the **data_property** parameter as my RGB and the **data_uncertainty** as my opacity.

I basically would like to know if I can write

```
uncertainty[..., 0] = uncertainty[..., 1] = uncertainty[..., 2]
```

in another way, saying data for **uncertainty[..., 0 or 1 or 2]** the value should be **numpy.uint8(data_property * 255)**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new axis on the right using `data_property[..., np.newaxis]`. Then the assignment can be done like this:

```
uncertainty[..., :3] = numpy.uint8(data_property * 255)[..., np.newaxis]
```

---

For example,

```
In [49]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [50]: x
Out[50]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [51]: y = np.zeros((2,3,4))

In [52]: y[...,:3] = x[...,np.newaxis]

In [53]: y
Out[53]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  0.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  0.],
        [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  0.]]])

In [54]: np.allclose(y[...,0], x)
Out[54]: True

In [55]: np.allclose(y[...,1], x)
Out[55]: True

In [56]: np.allclose(y[...,2], x)
Out[56]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, as long as `data_property` has the same `shape` as `uncertainty[..., 0]`